# what is the derivative of the following?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

$$sin^{-1}(sec^{2}x)$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-sec^{4}x}}*2sec(x)sec(x)tan(x)$$

Correct?

When I go to graph this on desmos, it doesnt show up? What's up with this function?[image]

Its just a dot. Why? even the deriative i cant see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $\sec^2 x=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}>1$ for any $x\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)\setminus\{0\}.$ For that reason the $\arcsin$ doesn't exist. It only exists for $x=0$ and thus the graph reduces to a point.

Answer (score 2):

The domain of $\sin^{-1}x$ is $[-1,1]$ while the range of $\sec^2x$ is $[1,\infty)$